# Floor all numbers in an array using regular expression

Tags: regex, preg-replace, notepad++

I have a 53MB file containing a lot of arrays in the form of:

```
[ 730762.36433458142, 7043260.1900061285 ]
```

There are always two numbers in the array and I want to use regular expression replace in Notepad++, so the array become of the form:

```
[ 730762, 7043260 ]
```

So strip the digits after the comma from the number.

The problem is that there are also comma numbers outside these arrays, which should stay intact.

Does anyone know which regex expression I can use?

EDIT:
The solution that @npinti provides makes my editor crash. I always used an expression with lookbehind and lookahead that only finds the dot and digits after the comma, and replace that with an empty string, but I can't find it any more.

May be the provided solutions cost to much memory? I don't know.

Comment: This is not difficult, you only need to describe the array (with brackets) in your pattern.

Comment: @machro What regular expression do you *think* you can use? You must have thought of something.

Comment: @Tomalak One with lookbehind and lookahead. But I don't know how to use them :(

Comment: You need neither anyway. You only need to describe this pattern: Opening square brackets, digits, dot, more digits, comma, digits, dot, more digits, closing square bracket. It really is extremely straight forward.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, I know it COULD be straight forward. But the simple solution crashes my editor.

Comment: Then it's time for an update maybe? This expression should definitely not crash the program.

Comment: @Tomalak As mentioned in http://superuser.com/questions/514374/regex-find-replace-big-file, it is not uncommon with such large files.

Comment: @machro If your text editor crashes on a meager 50 MB text file then your editor is either crap (sorry to say it) or has a glaring bug and needs updating. Crashing certainly is neither acceptable nor "common" (i.e. something that can't be helped).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like so: `\[\s+(\d+)\.\d+,\s+(\d+)\.\d+\s+]` and replace it with `[ \1, \2 ]`.

Given this:

```
[ 730762.36433458142, 7043260.1900061285 ]
[ 123.36433458142, 456.1900061285 ]
[ 456.36433458142, 789.1900061285 ]
123.123,123.456
456.789,456.1010
[ 789.36433458142, 987.1900061285 ]
[ 987.36433458142, 654.1900061285 ]
```

Yields

```
[ 730762, 7043260 ]
[ 123, 456 ]
[ 456, 789 ]
123.123,123.456
456.789,456.1010
[ 789, 987 ]
[ 987, 654 ]
```

Comment: @machro: What would happen if you where to try with a small subset of your data?

Comment: @npitni Then it worked. Looked like I needed to update my notepad++.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to match

```
\[( \d+)\.\d+,( \d+)\.\d+ \]
```

And replace with `[\1,\2 ]`